# R: Shiny - update dateRangeInput start and end

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using 'shiny' in RStudio.

I would like the pre-selected dates of the dateRangeInput widget to be updated with the min and max of a dataset. 
When I try the code below (simplified for the start date only), the start date does not show up in the left box of the date range widget: instead, the box appears blank (but it is actually set as today's date - on clicking on the empty box, the calendar with today's date shows up). 
*ui.r: dateRangeInput("dates", label = "Date range", start='mydatestart', end = '2014-05-06')*

The minimum date is actually selected since it shows up when using 
*ui.r: textOutput('mydatestart')*

Here is a reproducible example: 
ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI({
  sidebarPanel(
  dateRangeInput("dates", label = "Date range", start='mydatestart', end = '2014-05-06'),
  textOutput('mydatestart')
  )
})
```

server.R

```
  
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  mydate<-c("2013-04-24", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-26", "2013-04-27", "2013-04-28", "2013-04-28", "2013-04-29", "2013-04-30")
  output$mydatestart<-renderText(min(mydate))
})
```

Using *output$mydatestart<-renderText(as.Date(min(mydate)))* gives the same issue.

Do you know why this is happening?
Thanks, 
Yvan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `dateRangeInput`into `server.R` so you can use any object defined there as arguments:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI({
    sidebarPanel(
        htmlOutput("selector"),
        textOutput('mydatestart')
    )
})

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    mydate<-c("2013-04-24", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-26", "2013-04-27", "2013-04-28", "2013-04-28", "2013-04-29", "2013-04-30")
    output$mydatestart<-renderText({min(mydate)})

    output$selector <- renderUI({

        dateRangeInput("dates", label = "Date range"
                       , start=min(mydate), end = '2014-05-06')

    })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You can't pass a string literal like `mydatestart` as an argument to `dateRangeInput` because it will interpret is as just that - a string - which is why the `start` field was empty. You need to give it a legitimate value.
2. There were a couple of key functions missing from your `shinyUI` call, indicated with comments below.
3. It's a little more idiomatic to put global data objects in a `global.R` file for your shiny applications, rather than defining them inside of the `shinyServer` function.

---

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI({
  ## fluidPage(...)
  fluidPage(
    ## sidebarLayout(...)
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        dateRangeInput(
          "dates", label = "Date range",
          start = min(mydate),
          end = '2014-05-06'),
        uiOutput("mydatestart2")
      ),

      mainPanel(textOutput('mydatestart'))
    )
  )

})
```

---

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # not accessable in UI
  output$mydatestart <- renderText(min(mydate))
  # accessable in UI
  output$mydatestart2 <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput(
      "dates2",
      label = "Reactive Start Date",
      start = as.Date(input$dates[1]) + 7,
      end = as.Date(input$dates[1]) + 14
    )
  })
})
```

---

**global.R**

```
mydate <- c("2013-04-24", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-26",
            "2013-04-27", "2013-04-28", "2013-04-28",
            "2013-04-29", "2013-04-30")
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It works indeed in this example. However, how would you get the same result using an *output* object (like *'mydatestart'* in the example) in server.R? 
I want to use this widget as part of a bigger shiny app in which the user uploads a dataset. The dateRangeInput widget would then need to get the min and max dates from that uploaded dataset. Do you recommend using a renderUI() in server.R instead?

Comment: I can't mark it as such, but your script is also a good answer, using *uiOutput()* in ui.R - instead of *htmlOutput()* in @Andriy_T's

Comment: Good point about `uiOutput` but I don't really see the difference with `htmlOutput`

Comment: from [shiny site](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/htmlOutput.html): _uiOutput is intended to be used with renderUI on the server side. It is currently just an alias for htmlOutput_. So yes, It is correct to use `uiOutput` for a future changes but for now there is no difference

Comment: Never claimed there was a difference. Just following up on my original answer.