# force Shiny's updateDateRangeInput to send a message to the client immediately (or how to initialize dateRangeInput with data values from the server)

Tags: r, shiny

I have a little `shiny` app that uses a `dateRangeInput` to plot only a subset of the data.

I was trying to initialize the values of the `dateRangeInput` (max, min, start, end) to match those of the data set (plot the whole range by default).

One way to do that is to use `updateDateRangeInput`. It works, but only after an error that gets briefly displayed on the UI. (I also tried the solution discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560562/setting-daterangeinput-min-max-based-on-data), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975794/r-shiny-update-daterangeinput-start-and-end) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605457/r-shiny-daterangeinput-update-based-on-input-file), which is using `uiOutput` in the UI and `renderUI` on the server side, but I found basically the same problem).

Here's my (hopefully minimal) reproducible example (if you have `shiny` installed, you should be able to just copy and paste the code to see what I mean):

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

get_data <- function(){
    set.seed(1234567)
    data.frame(
        date = sort(sample(seq(as.Date('2014/01/01'), as.Date('2017/01/01'), by = "day"), 200)),
        value = runif(200)
    )
}

# Here's my UI
ui <- fluidPage(

    dateRangeInput("dateRange", label = "Date range"),

    plotOutput(outputId = "thePlot", height = "520px")
)

# And here's my server
server <- function(input, output, clientData, session) {

    the_data <- reactive({
        # Get the data
        my_data <- get_data()
        # And update the date range values to match those of the dataset
        updateDateRangeInput(
            session = session,
            inputId = "dateRange",
            start = min(my_data$date),
            end = max(my_data$date)
        )
        my_data
    })

    output$thePlot <- renderPlot({
        # I need to subset the data, using the user input (dateRangeInput)
        data_subset <- dplyr::filter(the_data(),
                                     date >= input$dateRange[[1]],
                                     date <= input$dateRange[[2]]
        )

        str(data_subset)
        # And plot the subset of data
        plot(x = data_subset$date, 
             y = data_subset$value)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So this app basically loads a dataset, which I do not know in advance, therefore, I do not know the date range to hard code it on the UI.

The UI only has the `dateRangeInput` and a `plotOutput`. The server side defines a `reactive` expression to load the data and a `renderPlot` that only subsets the data using the range given by the `dateRangeInput` on the UI.

Note that the `dateRangeInput` on UI does not have max, min, start or end dates defined (therefore, the default NULL values are used). That's is because at this point I have no clue on the values, only at run time when the data is loaded I know what would be the appropriate values (the whole range of the data). Of course I can set some arbitrary values on UI, but they will be just that, arbitrary values that may or may not work.

So what I wanted to do is for my app to load the data and update the `dateRangeInput` with appropriate values. I am doing this just after loading the data. It works, but after stumbling on an error on the `renderPlot`.

What happens is that `renderPlot` gets executed before the `dateRangeInput` values are updated, therefore, `renderPlot` is using NULL values to subset the data and this leads to an error. This error is briefly displayed to the user. Then, the `dateRangeInput` values do get updated and the plot rendered properly.

I checked the flow and `updateDateRangeInput` is indeed executed before `renderPlot`. However, the values are actually updated lated on.

This behaviour is actually described on the help page of `updateDateRangeInput`:

> The input updater functions send a message to the client, telling it
>   to change the settings of an input object. The messages are collected
>   and sent after all the observers (including outputs) have finished
>   running.

So, even though `updateDateRangeInput` get executed before `renderPlot`, it only collects the message which is only sent to the client after `renderPlot` finished running.

Is there any way to force `updateDateRangeInput` to send the messages to the client immediately?

Or how can I initialize the values of a `dateRangeInput` from the server side before other outputs are executed?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for such a long message (as the saying goes, I did not have time to write a short message, but I hope the reproducible example is as short as it gets to illustrate my problem).

Comment: Wrap your plot function in `if (nrow(subset_data)) {...}`. There is zero row data frame during the rendering phase and `plot` does not like it. Replacing `plot` with `ggplot` works without that wrap because `ggplot` handles it more gracefully.

Comment: Similar to the comment above, you could use:
`if(nrow(data_subset) == 0) return(NULL)`
the line before you run the plot.
This is a fairly common problem with R shiny, often with `NULL` inputs causing the error. It is so common that a recent shiny release has a new function `req()` (http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html) that checks for `NULL` values. In your case, you cannot use `req()` because your data is not `NULL`, but rather has zero rows.

Comment: thanks @Gopala and @easports611 this is very helpful. I was reluctant to engage in conditions checking because I have a bunch of them and I would have to do it for all of them (and they all have to fail early for the dates to get updated). I guess I agree with the article on `req()` "it seems a shame that such a simple app needs [many] different manual checks and early returns". There should be an easier way to initialize input values on the UI from the server side. For the moment I will use @easports611's solution, but kind of forcing the use of `req()`  `if(nrow(data_subset) == 0) req(NULL)`

Comment: You can use `req` as follows: `req(nrow(data_subset) != 0)`  - without forcing anything. `NULL` is just one of many values that are considered  by `req` as  `falsy` values. (`?req`)